# Gradient for border in Android

Tags: android, border, gradient

I have some text in a relative layout.I know that we can draw a border with curves using stroke and corner in a separate xml.
Is there a way to apply gradient effect for the border constructed with the stroke? or is there any other way to draw a gradient border?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that trivially, but it seems like you could define two shape drawables and combine with a layer drawable.  The bottom one would be a rounded corner rectangle with a gradient, the top one would be a slightly smaller rounded corner rectangle of whatever you wanted the interior color to be.  The effect should be something like a stroke gradient, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: I have tried that option too. It just looks like a thick stroke.

Comment: I did it though .9.png image set as background. Made a gradient bordered .9.png with expendable sides and used that image as background